# How to get Content Uri from Document file path?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am able to get Media (Image and Video) Content Uri from following code

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile, String type) {
        if (type != null && type.equals(Constants.IMAGE)) {
            String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                    new String[]{filePath}, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                cursor.close();
                return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
            } else {
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                    return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } else if (type != null && type.equals(Constants.VIDEO)) {
            String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media._ID},
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                    new String[]{filePath}, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                cursor.close();
                return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
            } else {
                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, filePath);
                    return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But for Document files like text, pdf and etc. I am un able get Content Uri.

Note: Uri.fromFile() **does not** work for Content Uri.

Content Uri Example: content://media/external/file/17277

Comment: Please explain first what your code does.

Comment: Realise that your code is only usable for devices up to Android 9. This because you use the .DATA column.